# jQuery Mobile - move to next/previous pages - performing action twice after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM project - a number of pages with a left arrow and a right arrow independent of them that control moving between the pages - beginning at the first, then tapping the right arrow to move to the next, then possibly back, then forward etc etc hopefully you get the picture..

Problem is: when the site loads up, the right arrow takes you to the next page as normal, then when you tap the right arrow again, it skips over the next page and goes to the page AFTER the next one. It has a slide ani and you can see the next page, but then totally just fires again without me touching it and moves again to the next one.

I'm also using swipe gestures to perform the same function and they work FINE. Just tapping the arrows gives this result.

**Any ideas gratefully welcomed!!**

JS:

```
$(document).bind('pagecreate', function (e) { 

/Navigation for next/prev arrows   

    $(document).on('click', '.right-arrow', function () {

    if ($.mobile.activePage.next('.page-container').length !== 0) {
    var next = $.mobile.activePage.next('.page-container');

    resetCasePages()
    $.mobile.changePage(next, {
    transition: 'slide'
   });

} 
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', '.left-arrow', function () {

   if ($.mobile.activePage.prev('.page-container').length !== 0) {
   var prev = $.mobile.activePage.prev('.page-container');

   resetCasePages()
   $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
   transition: 'slide',
   reverse: true
   });

   }
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});


//Swipe to the right of screen (swipeleft)

$( ".page-container" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeHandler );

function swipeHandler( event ){

if ($.mobile.activePage.next('.page-container').length !== 0) {
    var next = $.mobile.activePage.next('.page-container');
    resetCasePages()
    $.mobile.changePage(next, {
    transition: 'slide'
   });
   } 
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}


//Swipe to the left of screen (swiperight)

 $( ".page-container" ).on( "swiperight", swipeHandler2 );

 function swipeHandler2( event ){

  if ($.mobile.activePage.prev('.page-container').length !== 0) {
    var prev = $.mobile.activePage.prev('.page-container');
    resetCasePages()
    $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
    transition: 'slide',
    reverse: true
   });
  }
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
}); 
});

//function to reset case pages on arrow

function resetCasePages() {
$('.rationale-box').hide();
$('.answer-yes').removeClass('correct-style');
$('.answer-yes').removeClass('incorrect-style');
$('.answer-no').removeClass('correct-style');
$('.answer-no').removeClass('incorrect-style');
$('.incorrect').removeClass('inhibit');
}

//function diagnosis pages
function diagnosisPages() {

$("#slider").slider('value',2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `event` as an argument to your click functions as you are doing on your swipe listeners.

```
$(document).on('click', '.right-arrow', function (event) {

    if ($.mobile.activePage.next('.page-container').length !== 0) {
    var next = $.mobile.activePage.next('.page-container');

    resetCasePages()
    $.mobile.changePage(next, {
    transition: 'slide'
   });

} 
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', '.left-arrow', function (event) {

   if ($.mobile.activePage.prev('.page-container').length !== 0) {
   var prev = $.mobile.activePage.prev('.page-container');

   resetCasePages()
   $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
   transition: 'slide',
   reverse: true
   });

   }
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```